# work with macro in emacs of prelude

Tags: emacs

I am trying to use emacs macro, and I need to type a ", but in my prelude emacs with evil enabled, it will automatically add another " to make it a pair, so I need to delete that ", but that will interfere with macro. So how to disable the automatically adding of "? I used C-h m to get all the minor modes as below, but I don't know which mode caused automatical adding of ", so is there any way to disable ALL monir mode, or any suggestion to work with macro in prelude?

```
Enabled minor modes: Anzu Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Column-Number Company Delete-Selection
Diff-Auto-Refine Eldoc Elisp-Slime-Nav Erc-Spelling Erc-Track
Erc-Truncate Evil Evil-Local Evil-Surround File-Name-Shadow Flyspell
Font-Lock Global-Anzu Global-Auto-Revert Global-Company Global-Diff-Hl
Global-Ede Global-Evil-Surround Global-Flycheck Global-Font-Lock
Global-Hl-Line Global-Linum Global-Semantic-Idle-Scheduler
Global-Semanticdb Global-Undo-Tree Golden-Ratio Guide-Key Helm
Helm-Descbinds Helm-Match-Plugin Helm-Occur-Match-Plugin Line-Number
Linum Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Prelude Prelude-Global Projectile
Projectile-Global Rainbow Rainbow-Delimiters Recentf Savehist Semantic
Shell-Dirtrack Show-Smartparens Show-Smartparens-Global
Size-Indication Smartparens Smartparens-Strict Text-Scale Tooltip
Transient-Mark Undo-Tree Volatile-Highlights Which-Function Whitespace
Winner Yas Yas-Global
```

Comment: It's smartparens, probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`describe-key(C-h k)` function shows the key & the command it will run when that key is pressed.

So, `C-h k "` will show the function which is trying to add its pair.

Most probably it will be smartparens or paredit.